# Calling Rest Api with HTTP authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, rest, c#-4.0

I have to call a `Rest API` securely. I have an `authenticate API` which returns a token. I need to add this token the API I am calling.

This is the usual way I know of calling the `Rest API`. I need to append string token to this request.

```
        // *** Establish the request 
        string token= getAuthenticate(username,password,out token );
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lcUrl);
        // *** Retrieve request info headers
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string lcHtml = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        loResponseStream.Close();
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any Error? your question is not clear...

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what's the problem... To get the response from the `Rest Uri` you can do like below :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(yourUrl + token); // Append Here
        request.Method = "GET"; // GET or POST Define Here
        //http.Accept = "application/json"; // Add if require
        //http.ContentType = "application/json"; // Add if require
        String test = String.Empty;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            test = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
```

`Or` You can use Simple requests through **`WebClient`:**

For Example:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string json = string.Empty;
// Downloads JSon String
json = webClient.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"); // Replace your URL + Token...
```

There is third party component also available = `RestSharp`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `HttpClient`, no different at all. I thought this way more clean : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

```
var uri = "http://example.com";
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token_you_want_to_used);

     var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
     string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```